# ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed. (error running Spleeter using Python)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to utilize an open-source AI called Spleeter to separate and acquire song stems, but after following the instructions in this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WmThLASBpMI) and verifying that everything installed correctly, I get slapped with what looks to be two exception instances of errors upon trying to run the splitting process:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\jacob\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "c:\users\jacob\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "c:\users\jacob\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "c:\users\jacob\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "c:\users\jacob\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jacob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\spleeter-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('spleeter==1.5.0', 'console_scripts', 'spleeter')()
  File "c:\users\jacob\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\spleeter\__main__.py", line 54, in entrypoint
    main(sys.argv)
  File "c:\users\jacob\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\spleeter\__main__.py", line 36, in main
    enable_logging()
  File "c:\users\jacob\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\spleeter\utils\logging.py", line 60, in enable_logging
    tf_logger = get_tensorflow_logger()
  File "c:\users\jacob\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\spleeter\utils\logging.py", line 27, in get_tensorflow_logger
    from tensorflow.compat.v1 import logging
  File "c:\users\jacob\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 99, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "c:\users\jacob\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "c:\users\jacob\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "c:\users\jacob\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "c:\users\jacob\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "c:\users\jacob\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "c:\users\jacob\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\jacob\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "c:\users\jacob\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "c:\users\jacob\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "c:\users\jacob\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "c:\users\jacob\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
```

I did try using Anaconda for Spleeter beforehand but it was failing with no Errors, so I made sure to uninstall and remove all files regarding that and Spleeter for fresh installs before switching to Python. Probably not relevant, but more info never hurt anyone.

I'm not very well versed in this sort of stuff, but if there's a known fix I'd like to know. Thank you.

Versions:

Python: 3.6.2 x64 bit

pip: 9.0.1

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem, then came up against a catch-22 solution: pip install tensorflow==2.0

This supposedly takes care of the missing dll but while tensorflow was installing I got an error that spleeter needs tensorflow 1.15.2 and is incompatible with 2.0. I tried installing 1.15.2 again but got the same dll error again. That might be worth a try though.

Have you tried the spleeter GUI?
Download at https://makenweb.com

That worked for me and it downloaded some extra files it needed. I'm just trying to get the command line version running because the GUI seems to have a problem with a few files, where it'll load and process an audio file but doesn't write the output files. I've tried rewriting the audio files with various wav and mp3 settings without success.